# How do we work on tables and do calculations with their values? (for a beginner)

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and I am trying to figure out how to work with a table.

It is very basic, the table has student name, student number, 4 lab marks, 1 midterm mark, and 4 exam marks. We are asked to find the person with the highest total lab mark. Now, not being familiar with coding I am not sure where to start. First of all, prof gave us these codes beforehand, I believe it's for loading and setting id number and name as strings

```
opts = detectImportOptions("course_grades_2021.xlsx")
opts = setvartype(opts,{'ID_Number','Name'},'string')
table = readtable('course_grades_2021.xlsx', opts);
```

I tried adding the values but it doesn't work like a matrix, when I for example get a lab mark for a student Matlab shows it as

```
ans =

  table

    Lab_1
    _____

      3
```

We are not allowed to convert to a matrix, could anyone show me how I should do this? Matlab is very vital for my program and I really need to learn this

Comment: Looks like you need the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) for accessing data in a table. This site is for specific questions and answers rather than broad guidance on syntax. That said, in this case you just want something like `tbl.Lab_1 + tbl.Lab_2`, note you shouldn't shadow the built-in `table` keyword as a variable name like in your example.

Comment: Hi Wolfie, I used the link and solved it thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation shared by wolfie helped.

I used

```
Lab1_Marks= table.Lab_1(2:21,:);
Lab2_Marks= table.Lab_2(2:21,:);
Lab3_Marks= table.Lab_3(2:21,:);
Lab4_Marks= table.Lab_4(2:21,:);
```

to pull only the marks from the table